# MATE terminal - remove color from prompt

Tags: gnome-terminal, mate

I want my terminal prompt to be the same color as text, or black -- I am happy with either.

After applying these changes I have restarted my session by one or all of the methods I give below.

Modifications tried :

I have tried modifying `.bashrc` as so:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Changing the value of `color_prompt` to 'no' and to ''

No effect.

I have tried modifying `.bashrc` to set `color_prompt` unconditionally to some value other than `yes` *immediately* before it is tested. Like this:

```
color_prompt=''

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\ 
 [\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
 else
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
 fi
```

To no effect.

I have tried new session :

```
su - stephen
```

Restarting the desktop manager

```
 sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

And restarting the system

```
 reboot
```

To no effect.

What have I missed?

Comment: FYI:  MATE software started as a fork, but to call it that now would be very wrong.  The MATE code was all GTK2 when forked, the move to GTK3 was done by MATE devs themselves post-fork, so the code base is very different to the once forked code (or modern gnome3 code; they didn't re-base their code on the later GNOME3 code but ported to GTK3 themselves from MATE's old forked code).

Comment: @guiverc Ah thank you. I'll correct the question.